Fix mistake made halfway between transferring from Android to iPhone with iOS app
Is there any way to start the process of migrating from Android to iPhone using the iOS app (com.apple.movetoios) from scratch, after I made a mistake during a previous attempt?
The process of moving from Android to Apple is strange, poorly documented and time-consuming. I made a mistake during the step where on the Android device, using the iOS app, I had to select many rows of data to transfer. I did not see that I had to scroll for more rows, I was excited that after many attempts Apple finally presented the 'transfer screen' and I wanted to move on before any of the 3 devices necessary during the process went back to sleep or ran out of power.
As a result, only part of the personal data from Android was transferred to the iPhone.
I wiped to iPhone yet again, to try and fix it, but now Apple installed the iPhone with the partial data that was already tied to the iCloud account.
The problem is, I used a real name to create the iCloud account and it's my child's account. If I make a new iCloud account it will always be the Childsname Lastname_1 account. (but maybe that is the price to pay)

Since it’s not yet clear from your description, is the mistake in setting up an Apple account that is tied to iCloud service? (FWIW, Apple offers custom individual setup for iPhone users as well as support for Apple Account and iCloud online that is quite good.) is there a reason you’re not asking them for help deciding how you want your iCloud accounts to be? You get free AppleCare for 90 days https://support.apple.com/complimentary use it!

Of course you can erase your iPhone (or all three if that’s how many times you will do this process) and start over.
I would talk with Apple support first and write down on paper what Apple Accounts you have created now and in the past. If you have no previous history with purchases, they can advise if you’re better off starting with an entirely new adult iCloud account (not using a phone or an external email for your Apple Account log in identity) and help looking up if you previously used a phone or email with Apple Account or Apple ID or other service in the past.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/118670

The easy part will be sorting the data transfer. Sorting out the account details is the problematic part since you can’t reuse some parts of your identity if you make a new Apple Account, even if you properly follow all the steps to first delete a previous account.
The reason to avoid third party identification is this part of the deletion article linked above:

Can I use the primary email address for my deleted Apple Account to create a new Apple Account or with another existing Apple Account?
No, once your Apple Account is deleted, you can’t use the email address that you used with it to create a new Apple Account for as long as Apple retains the one-way hash of the email address. For third-party (non-Apple) domain accounts, the one-way hash is deleted after six years.


Now for the easy part, erasing your phone is easy from the device or from a computer.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/erase-iphone-iph7a2a9399b/ios


I can erase the iPhone, but when I configure it again it will download the faulty data again. I have tried this already. I need to cleanse the iCloud data of the partial Android data.

You point about Apple Account details is very useful, thank you.

Yes, you can purge all iCloud data from any somewhat modern web browser on a computer before you start over. https://www.icloud.com/ If you run into any issues deleting data, absolutely work with a Apple Support. Explain how you got partial data, they will help you out. They can see account details we can’t and they help people like you day after day after day and know all the common misunderstandings and best fixes.

The answer by @bmike pointed me in the right direction, I talked to apple support and they confirmed I could still repeat the process and copy data from Android to iPhone.
Unfortunately copying app accounts does not really work, see point 3 below.
Three things about transferring data from Android to iPhone:
1 - When to transfer data: After some 20 screens to click/swipe through during iPhone setup, you will get to the "Hello" screen again. Next, the screen below appears:
There are 5 options to choose from, the last options is the one that lets you transfer data from Android. I don't know what it is in English, the Dutch version translates to something like "Make adjustments".

2 - How to transfer data: After connecting to Adroid do not forget to scroll to see and select all the data you want to transfer!

3 - And finally you cannot transfer application-accounts with this method. Say you have Pokemon Go on Android, the process described will result in a Pokemon Go icon on your iPhone. The icon is just a downloadlink, you still have to install the app, and than you have to find out what credentials you were using, and manually type them in on the iPhone.
It may be that this is only the case for a childs iPhone and it is possible to transfer account-data when setting up an iPhone for a adult user.
